# Cron job with php

Tags: php, cron

How can you do a cron job with php without creating a cron Job on the server cron software

Is that even possible ?

EDIT
as I added in a comment I've seen a script called piwik who does that kind of stuff, e.g. Sends emails without any cron job

Comment: Why don't you want to use cron as is? - Brute force solution is for you to be the cron (check in on a web page that executes what you want every x hours) ;)

Comment: Okay so I saw this webapp called piwik and I never set a cron job for her and it's sending emails every week/month

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best you could do is make a cron job that periodically checks a file X for cron jobs and runs them.  Then all you would have to do is add jobs to X instead of to cron.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can try online services like http://pingability.com/

Cron is ideal though.

Answer (score -2):

```
set_time_out(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

while(1){
sleep(1); // sleep one sec every time.
//do your stuff here..
//you can use time() with IF to make it execute something only on specific timing.
}
```

Not recommended.

Comment: @Mob thats why the "Not recommended", but its not impossible to do that.

Comment: IMO, if something is not recommended, don't post it. People have a habit of blindly copy+pasting whatever they see that seems to work. Keeping a PHP process running like this is a huge resource hog, won't work at all on shared hosting, and bound to crash eventually. It's not a viable solution.

Comment: Not a good thing, you can first use any outside free cron to trigger a script or you can use a page of your site to trigger a task anytime it gets visited, just launch another page in the background to do some work in parallel and use a job processing system like i described in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621025/start-stop-php-script-from-backend-administrative-webpage/7621789#7621789